# Setting file pointer beyond the end of file on SMB share

Tags: winapi, file-io, smb

Suppose Z is a network mapped drive, connected over samba.
There are two code snippets:

```
{//block A
    HANDLE hndl = CreateFile(L"Z:\\file1.bin", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER pos, out;
    pos.QuadPart = 1073741824ULL;
    DWORD res = SetFilePointerEx(hndl, pos, &out, FILE_BEGIN);
    DWORD written;
    SetEndOfFile(hndl);
    WriteFile(hndl, &hndl, sizeof(hndl), &written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hndl);
}

{//block B
    HANDLE hndl = CreateFile(L"Z:\\file2.bin", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER pos, out;
    pos.QuadPart = 1073741824ULL;
    DWORD res = SetFilePointerEx(hndl, pos, &out, FILE_BEGIN);
    DWORD written;
    SetEndOfFile(hndl);
    WriteFile(hndl, &hndl, sizeof(hndl), &written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hndl);
}
```

As you see, for block B, the difference is only in access mode used when opening the file. 
However, this difference causes huge difference in opration:
Block A is executed almost instantaneously, while block B causes a data transfer of more than 1GB over the network.
Is there a way to avoid transferring that much data for block B?

Comment: if it is not required to reread the already written data, you may try to separately (non-exclusivly) open that file in read mode and write mode. you may search for overlapped io (not sure if this applies to files)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, the point is that I need a single handle be opened for both reading and writing. I hoped to understand what mechanism or subsystem causes this behavior.